# Constructor Dependency Injection in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

As far as I know **constructors injection enforces mandatory dependencies** and setters injection allow optional dependencies, but then...

Wouldn't be possible then this approach ???

```
@Component
public class Car {

    @Autowired(required=false)
    public Car(Engine engine, Transmission transmission) {
        this.engine = engine;
        this.transmission = transmission;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the best idea to let Car be managed by Spring. You can simply create a new Car... The CarService, however, could be managed by Spring

Comment: Also probably not the best idea to share an engine and transmission between different vehicles running at the same time ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach won't work as Spring will not inject `null` if no bean of given type is found. If you set `@Autowired(required=false)` on the setter method, in case there is no such bean this setter won't be called. It is not possible with the constructor.

For `Spring` version `4.1+` you can use Java 8 [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) for declaring optional dependencies:

```
@Component
public class Car {

    @Autowired
    public Car(Engine engine, Optional<Transmission> transmission) {
        this.engine = engine;
        this.transmission = transmission.orElse(null);
    }
}
```

In this case Spring will understand that `Engine` is required and but `Transmission` is optional. So if no bean of type `Transmission` is found then `Optional.empty()` is injected.